# Sorting arrays within an array by a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a single array looking like this:

```
var x = [[29,"Abc","9320","390"],[932,"123","9301","9032"], ...]
```

I'm looking to sort this array, so that it is organised by the first value of each array. In this case, that would look like this:

```
[[932,"123","9301","9032"], [29,"Abc","9320","390"], ...]
```

I've attempted to use `.forEach` but have been unable to get it working. Could anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the sorting logic.

Comment: Hi @John - I'm looking to print out all of these arrays by order of their first value, so those with the largest value will be printed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do with sort is this:

```
var sorted = x.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
}).reverse(); // the sort is in ascending order so we need to finally reverse the array to have your final array in descending order!
```

or even better:

```
var sorted = x.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[0] - a[0];
})
```

if you compare the values using a `<` or `>` it wont always work:

[Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison)

However for numbers using a '-' is fine:

[How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Comment: And now turn it around to get the descending sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var x = [[29,"Abc","9320","390"], [932,"123","9301","9032"]];

var sorted = x.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[0] - a[0];
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: The callback provided to the sort method should return a numerical value, negative, zero or positive. So `return b[0] - a[0]` would be more appropriate.